# Java code inside a test case

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-ide

In my code the daily emails generated by java code.
Is it possible to write pure java code inside a Selenium IDE automation test case?

Comment: Are you referring to Selenium IDE or Selenium Webdriver?

Comment: i am using Selenium IDE. Is it possible to write pure java code inside a selenium automation test case?

Comment: You can write it, it won't execute it, but you can still write it.

Comment: Why would you do that? What is the reason you want java code to be included in Selenium IDE?

Answer (score 1):

No, in no uncertain terms, you cannot put Java code inside a Selenium IDE test case.

If you want to write your test case in Java, you need to use Selenium Webdriver.